# convert unsigned integer to unsigned char *

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

I want to get the value from unsigned int to unsigned char *, my logic gives wrong value

```
unsigned int Address = 0x0a5b0644; // this value is getting ss fun parameter
m_Address        = (unsigned char*)Address;  // this logic wrote in side C++ file

unsigned char * m_Address; // this is declared inside H file
```

Here m_Address is not gettting value 0x0a5b0644

Can I get some idea to do this

Comment: What value _is_ it getting?

Comment: Mmmmh, could this be a case where [`reinterpret_cast<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) would help ?

Comment: I am getting some junk value 0xFFFF80

Comment: Please show how you determine the value of `m_Address` as `0xFFFF80`.  I suspect the issue lies there.  Maybe `0xFFFF80` is the _address_ of `m_Address` and not its value?

Answer (score 2):

Converting from integer type to pointer will be implementation defined.

If you really need an unsigned integer type to store pointers, use `uintptr_t`(or `intptr_t`for signed integer type) in `<cstdint>`. They are introduced in **C++11** as an optional feature. They are capable of converting to `void *` type and converting back.

Comment: @Griwes: They are. See § 7.20.1.4 from C11 (same in C99).

Answer (score 0):

you may try the follow
assuming unsigned int is 4 bytes, {0x0a, 0x5b, 0x06, 0x44}

```
unsigned char bytes[11];// the number of charactoer in the string + a null terminating
sprintf(bytes, "%#04x", Address); //<here it will print it
```